# Powerbuilder Workspace Properties won't open

Tags: powerbuilder

When I try to open my workspace properties on Powerbuilder 12.6 it just freezes.
I tried to create a new Workspace without source control, but that doesn't work either. I tried to add

```
[JavaVM]
CreateJavaVM=0
```

to the pb.ini and put ReopenWorkspace=0 without success. I even deleted the layout => default folder in my registry (after exporting it), which was mentioned in a simmilar post about this problem.

Comment: Can you create a new workspace?  Can you open it?

Comment: Yes I can create a Workspace and can open it, but I can't open its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. The problem was, that the Properties-Window opened off-screen and I couldn't see it. I pressed Alt+Tab and then Alt+Space and chose relocate to move my window with the Arrow-Keys.

Comment: I work with remote desktop connections and this happens FREQUENTLY when my RDC session is interrupted. Good catch!

Comment: An alternate method is to temporarily change your screen resolution it will kick the window back into view.

Answer (score 0):

By itself a workspace shouldn't give you any problems.  Most likely it is a target contained within the workspace.  In the folder structure you are working with you will have a .pbt file for each target.  If you know which target PB is trying to load when it opens you can either remove the file or just rename the extension from .pbt to .bak or similar.
Then you can open the PB workspace.  PB will complain that it can't find the target but you can just close that nag window.  At least at this point you can go to another target, regenerate, get latest versions, or whatnot.

Comment: My workspace is functioning. I can do check outs and check ins, but I cant do a diff or open the Properties of the Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Just same fixed for myself. Properties forms opens out of screen area. So use 'move window' option... Alt + Blank and then use arrow keys to move it in visible screen area